# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for compiled emacs via X11

Tags: macos, ssh, x11-forwarding

I compiled `emacs` from source (using `g++`) on my work Mac (on which I do not have root access). Now, I wanted to make a test, whereby I open the compiled `Emacs.app` while being logged in via ssh. However, the output is

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file [...]

On the other hand, using `gnuplot`'s x11 terminal works as expected. How do I have to start emacs to see the window on the device I use x11 from?

### Edit

I configured the build as

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/emacs-26-3 --with-gnutls=no
```

The app is located in the `nextstep` directory and works as expected, when opened directly on the machine (i.e. not via ssh).

Comment: When you built emacs, how did you configure it?

Comment: @Kenster I edited my question to answer that question.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this? I get the same error when using CMake's BundleUtilities.

Comment: @oarfish Unfortunately, I have not found a solution. This seems to be related to the fact that when I am not logged into the machine (that is via TeamViewer or directly "on-site") there is no active Window manager or somthing similar thus it is not possible to open a window. (This was a while ago and this was only a guess from my memory)

Comment: In my case, i could actually get some info via the system log (open Console app and filter by your program's name). In my case, this alerted me to the fact some qt5 business was not correctly bundled. Don't know if this would have helped you.